# Is it a good idea to do checking preconditions and do some logic during implicit casting

Tags: c#

Full implementation is here https://gist.github.com/1306491
I'm using struct with implicit casting to implicitly convert to and from source type and describes check rule through generic parameters of the struct.
From my point of view it can reduce code repetition and can be read as an dsl.

How to use:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = Size(null);//result: argument exception
        Console.WriteLine(Lenght(null));//result 0
        DivByZero(0);// result: argument exception
        Log(5);//result: log 5 to console
        AddTenSymbols("");//result: if result string has lenght more than 10 then log result string/ 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Check<string, IsNotNull<string>> Size(Check<object, IsNotNull<object>> obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString();
    }

    static int Lenght(Check<string, AndReplaceByEmptyIfNull> str)
    {
        string stri = str;
        return stri.Length;
        //return ((string)str).Length;
    }

    static int DivByZero(Check<int, If<int, EqualsTo<Zero>, ThenThrowArgumentException<int>>> i)
    {
        return 1 / i;
    }

    static Check<int, If<int, BothTrue<Not<EqualsTo<Zero>>, Not<MoreThan<Ten>>>, ThenLog<int>>> Log(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
    static Check<string, If<string, Member<string, int, StringLenght, MoreThan<Ten>>, ThenLog<string>>> AddTenSymbols(string s)
    {
        return s + "asffgsdfgd"; ;
    }
```

Comment: It looks a bit over engineered and over complicated to me. You look like you are using C# generics like C++ templates and they are very different beasts. The fact that you have needed to create `Ten` and `Zero` classes / structs should tell you that this approach might not be right. In C++ `0` and `10` are actually perfectly good template parameters, but what happens here when you need 11 or 17?

Comment: Why would you use this over code contracts?

Comment: 1. I can inplace create new class it is not very big: class Illeven : Number {public Illeven():base(11)}

Comment: 2. code contracts is not really helpful with for example replace null string by empty. But my code can be easily merged with code contracts and use compile time checkings and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title-question: No, don't do that. Implicit casting should be safe and *not throw*.

From the C# Language specification, § 6.1 :

> The pre-defined implicit conversions always succeed and never cause
>   exceptions to be thrown. Properly designed user-defined implicit
>   conversions should exhibit these characteristics as well.

So if you do want validation, make it an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

By [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) and by the purpose of implicit casting your answer is **NO**.

> However, because implicit conversions do not require programmers to
>   explicitly cast from one type to the other, care must be taken to
>   prevent unexpected results. In general, implicit conversion operators
>   should never throw exceptions and never lose information so that they
>   can be used safely without the programmer's awareness. If a conversion
>   operator cannot meet those criteria, it should be marked explicit

Answer (score 0):

B Tyler is right, you're trying to capture the logic in types (by names) while you can easily go with lamdbas. and they will bring you more flexibility.

And your methods names are not expressing what the method is doing - for example `DivByZero` is not dividing by zero but by `i`... And your code won't run without exception. I don't see the point of this.

Comment: This is just an example and yes it is confusing.